# ubuntu-18.04.1 missing install/netboot/

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, pxe-boot, ubuntu-18.04

I'm working on setting up PXE boot server and while following some online instructions to mount the ISO and copy over everything under /mnt/install/netboot/, I noticed that a mount of ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.iso is missing the install/netboot/ directory, whereas under ubuntu-16.04.5-server-amd64.iso this directory exists.

In trying to make sure I use 18.04 files, am I looking in the wrong place of the 18.04 ISO or was this whole section dropped after 16.04?

## ubuntu-16.04.5:

```
alby@ubuntu:/$ sudo mount -o loop /var/tmp/ubuntu-16.04.5-server-amd64.iso /mnt

alby@ubuntu:/$ ls -l /mnt/install/netboot/
total 3
lr-xr-xr-x 1 root root   47 Jul 30 22:25 ldlinux.c32 -> ubuntu-installer/amd64/boot-screens/ldlinux.c32
lr-xr-xr-x 1 root root   33 Jul 30 22:25 pxelinux.0 -> ubuntu-installer/amd64/pxelinux.0
lr-xr-xr-x 1 root root   35 Jul 30 22:25 pxelinux.cfg -> ubuntu-installer/amd64/pxelinux.cfg
dr-xr-xr-x 1 root root 2048 Jul 30 22:16 ubuntu-installer
-r--r--r-- 2 root root   61 Jul 30 22:24 version.info
```

## ubuntu-18.04.1.0:

```
alby@ubuntu:/$ sudo mount -o loop /var/tmp/ubuntu-18.04.1.0-live-server-amd64.iso /mnt

alby@ubuntu:/$ ls -l /mnt/install/
total 179
-r--r--r-- 1 root root 182704 Jan 28  2016 mt86plus
alby@ubuntu:/$
```

Comment: What do you mean by mini.so? Or do you mean min.ISO?  I'm using full ISO files and the 18.04 doesn't appear to have the pxeboot files,whereas the 16.04 version does. I can only assume I need to use 16.04, because I just don't see where these files exist in 18.04.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am taking a similar online course and had the same issue.

What worked for me was to go to the Download section in www.ubuntu.com.

From the Ubuntu Server I choose "Use the traditional installer" link.

From there I scrolled up to "Network installer" and I choose the version that I wanted (18.04 LTS in my case).

It took me to a page with various architectures where I choose what worked for me (amd64 in my case).

From there I downloaded netboot.tar.gz and I extracted the content in to /var/lib/tftpboot.

With the dhcp and tftp active and properly configured I managed to boot a VM from Lan (as a boot method).
It brought me to the Installer boot menu and I completed an installation of a ubuntu-basic-server.

I hope it helped.

https://www.ubuntu.com/download/alternative-downloads#alternate-ubuntu-server-installer